# semantic segmentation with tensorflow - ValueError in loss function (sparse-softmax)

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-segmentation, softmax

So, I'm working on a building a fully convolutional network (FCN), based off of [Marvin Teichmann's tensorflow-fcn](https://github.com/MarvinTeichmann/tensorflow-fcn)

My input image data, for the time being is a 750x750x3 RGB image.
After running through the network, I use logits of shape [batch_size, 750,750,2] for my loss calculation.

It is a binary classification - I have 2 classes here, [0, 1] in my labels (of shape [batch_sizex750x750]. And these go into the loss function, below:

```
def loss(logits, labels, num_classes):
with tf.name_scope('loss mine'):
    logits = tf.to_float(tf.reshape(logits, [-1, num_classes]))

    #CHANGE labels type to int, for sparse_softmax...
    labels = tf.to_int64(tf.reshape(labels, [-1]))

    print ('shape of logits: %s' % str(logits.get_shape()))
    print ('shape of labels: %s' % str(labels.get_shape()))

    cross_entropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, labels, name='Cross_Entropy')
    tf.add_to_collection('losses', cross_entropy)

    loss = tf.add_n(tf.get_collection('losses'), name='total_loss')
return loss
```

These are shapes for the logits and labels after reshaping:

```
shape of logits: (562500, 2)
shape of labels: (562500,)
```

And here, it throws me a ValueError stating:

```
Shapes () and (562500,) are not compatible
```

Full traceback below:

```
  File "train.py", line 89, in <module>
loss_train = loss.loss(logits, data.train.labels, 2)
File "/tensorflow-fcn/loss.py", line 86, in loss
loss = tf.add_n(tf.get_collection('losses'), name='total_loss')
File "/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 88, in add_n
result = _op_def_lib.apply_op("AddN", inputs=inputs, name=name)
File "/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/op_def_library.py", line 704, in apply_op
op_def=op_def)
File "/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2262, in create_op
set_shapes_for_outputs(ret)
File "/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1702, in      set_shapes_for_outputs
shapes = shape_func(op)
File "/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 1557, in _AddNShape
merged_shape = merged_shape.merge_with(input_.get_shape())
File "/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 570, in merge_with
(self, other))
ValueError: Shapes () and (562500,) are not compatible
```

Suggestions? Is my implementation of the `tf.add_to_collection('losses', cross_entropy)` wrong?

UPDATE:

I tried to run this without the summing across pixels (or so I think), by returning `cross_entropy` in the above code directly, as the loss.

It seems to have worked. (It now throws a `ValueError` from the training optimizer function, stating: `No gradients provided for any variable`.
Assuming this has more to do with my weight initialization and regularization than anything else.

UPDATE 2:

The above (regarding ValueError due to absence of gradients) was trivial. As mentioned [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1511), this message is usually encountered when there is no path between any of the tf.Variable objects defined and the loss tensor that that is being minimized.

The initial problem with usage of `tf.add_n` persists though. I'm assuming it has to do with the mechanics of how Graph collections work in TensorFlow. Having initialized my variables, the error now reads:

```
Shapes () and (?,) are not compatible
```

Comment: Hi, murushiv, would you mind sharing more on how do you define logits of  shape [batch_size, 750,750,2] ?

Comment: @user288609 logits (unsure of my terminology here) of the batch size you mention, I extract from the model (the build method). Anything specific you want to know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closing. Turns out the code in the loss function was missing a mean summation. For anyone else facing this problem, modify the loss function as below, and it should work fine.

```
    cross_entropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, labels, name='Cross_Entropy')
    cross_entropy_mean = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy, name='xentropy_mean')
    tf.add_to_collection('losses', cross_entropy_mean)

    loss = tf.add_n(tf.get_collection('losses'), name='total_loss')
return loss
```

Comment: @OlivierMoindrot will do, once I'm allowed to.

Comment: When implementing the loss function, the result is nan. What's the reason resulting it? Thanks